# How can i use Angularjs and Datatables to display data in an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have my html table as below:

```html
<div>
  <table datatable="" class="table table-condensed" id="listTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAV ID</th>
        <th>NAV DATE</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>AMOUNT</th>
        <th>ADMIN FEE</th>
        <th>PURCHASE PRICE</th>
        <th>POSTED BY</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="navs in navs">
        <td>{{navs.NAV_ID}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.NAV_DATE}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.DESCRIPT}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.AMOUNT}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.ADMIN_FEE}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.P_PRICE}}</td>
        <td>{{navs.STAFFNAME}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and I have the js script to render the data in my html table. How can i use datatables plugins and the js file. i use the script below too load the values into my html page. the values are loaded well but i am stuck when it comes to displaying the data in a datatable

```js
 angular.module('CrudApp', []).
 config(['$routeProvider',
   function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
     when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'assets/templates/list.html',
       controller: ListCtrl
     }).
     when('/addNavs', {
       templateUrl: 'assets/templates/addNewNav.html',
       controller: AddCtrl
     }).
     otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/'
     });
   }
 ]);

 function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('api/getnavs').success(function(data) {
     $scope.navs = data;

   });
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. Are you creating custom directive, if so please share that code too.

Comment: Thank you. am not creating a custom directive.

Comment: ng-repeat="navs in navs" - shouldnt that be "nav in navs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your answers, they gave me great ideas to work around the task. i managed to figure out how to do it. I got an idea from [this](http://programwith.com/question_96006_how-to-attach-datatables-options-when-using-ui-router) and i managed to come up with this code that worked for me. Hope it helps someone with the same problem
app.controller('withOptionsCtrl', withOptionsCtrl);
function withOptionsCtrl($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder){

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDisplayLength(5)
    .withDOM('pitrfl');
$scope.dtColumnDefs=[
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible,
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notVisible,
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).notVisible,
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4).notVisible,
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notVisible,
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).notVisible
];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a back-end web services services which will directly communicate with the databases.

$http.get('api/getnavs').success(function(data) {
     $scope.navs = data;

});

By using this services calls retrieve data from server. you cannot access databases using front end programming languages like angular JS.

But there are opportunities for front end databases like pouch DB .

Comment: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-angularjs-and-php-more-power-with-resource/

Comment: I have a back-end web service that fetches the data from the database. I can display the data on the HTML table but having the data in jquery datatables giving me a hard time.